# Get local Files from Python lambda Function

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

i want get a file (List of files) located in my Local machine using a python lambda Function.

Im using the So library and try run local and works, but when y try run in aws my code does not detect the file.

I need verify a folder and it if has a file, upload this file to s3.  This process (Verification and upload) will run according to a schedule.

Batch file it´s not a option.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Sorry, but your requirements are difficult to understand. What do you mean by "get a file located on my local machine"? Are you saying that you are running an AWS Lambda function in the AWS Cloud and you want it to be able to access a file on your own computer that is somewhere on the Internet? Are are you wanting to access a file saved on the local disk of the Lambda function?

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein, when i use Azure logic apps, i can get files from mi local machine using a gateway connection provide by Azure... maybe amazaon has a equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are referring to: [Access data sources on premises - Azure Logic Apps | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-connection)

No, there is no equivalent for AWS Lambda functions.

An AWS Lambda function can access services on the Internet (eg make API calls, access websites), but you would need to code that yourself.

Comment: Yes, i know that Azure lagic apps i not equivalenbt for AWS Lambda function.

I search a equivalent (in AWS) for call or get file(s) from my local machine.

Comment: There is no functionality or service provided by AWS Lambda to get files from your local machine. You would need to write your own code to do this.